# Can parents stop me from doing things that is not haram or obligate me to do something that is not wajib?

Tags: parents

Does it matter if it's harus, makruh or sunnah?

If they can stop me from doing completely halal, then that sounds similar to the sin of making something haram to halal to me. Please clarify.

Comment: Please clearify what you are asking and what you mean witg "harus". The quran says you should follow and obey your parents instructions unless they ask you to do kufr, shirk or a sin. Also read [ask].

Comment: @Medi1Saif Harus, at least from where I am, means that it does not bring sin or reward if I do it. In other word, it means it is permissible.